# Winforms Get/Set between classes causing error - Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, winforms, get, set

Having trouble solving this one.  Might just be burned out tbh, ive been at this for hours.  I am new to Classes in C# and it is kicking the crap out of me trying to pass data between classes.  I know there are steps that I am missing, but microsoft docs is not being very helpful with my question so here goes.

Trying to pass values from once class to another.  The error code I am getting is CS0120

This is the format of what i am using within the first class

```
private void btn_Compute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal dL = Validator(box_Left.Text);
        decimal dR = Validator(box_Right.Text);
        decimal Answer = 0;
        string op = "";
        if (rad_Add.Checked == true)
        {
            MathFirstClass.Left = dL;
            MathFirstClass.Right = dR;
            op = " + ";
        }
}
```

and the code inside the other class that I am trying to send the data to looks like this

```
    decimal left;
    decimal right;
    decimal Answer;

    public decimal Left
    {
        get { return left; }
        set { left = value; }
    }

    public decimal Right
    {
        get { return right; }
        set { right = value; }
    }

    public decimal Add_Operands
    {
        get
        {
            Answer = Left + Right;
            return Answer;
        }
    }
```

Also if anyone wants to fill me in on how to send the answer back to the first class that would also be a great help.

Comment: So what do you want from this question? You have just implemented a two-variable addition operation and you can easily use it.

Comment: Except I can't, I'm getting an object reference error.

Comment: On which line are you getting the object reference error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an **instance** of your class.

```
private void btn_Compute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        decimal dL = Validator(box_Left.Text);
        decimal dR = Validator(box_Right.Text);
        decimal Answer = 0;
        string op = "";
        
        //****************************************
        MathFirstClass mathFirstClass = new MathFirstClass();
        
        if (rad_Add.Checked == true)
        {
            mathFirstClass.Left = dL;
            mathFirstClass.Right = dR;
            op = " + ";
        }
}
```

Comment: The variable is named `MathFirstClass` and it's of type `MathFirstClass`?  Would it be less confusing for the class and the variable to have different names?  (Your edit took care of this.  Thank you.)

Comment: So if I have other radio buttons, for example rad_Sub and rad_Mult will I need to add that line before every if() statement, or just the one time at the top?

Comment: @ jason44107 You can use the class name for naming, but the first letter should start with lowercase letters. You can search in Google for naming variables in C #

Comment: @KyleC Use the if (){} else if (){} structure

Comment: @MeysamAsadi ty